# Check if user input A or B and ignore whitespace in

Tags: c

I want to check if my user input is A or B
Inputs like: "`aA` `AA` `vbB` and so on would be **invalid**

white spaces **before** A and **after** A  ( or B ) are allowed:

Input check should run until user inputs valid character (A or B) or unti EOF (ctrl+D).

My code has Basics for this but not sure how to do the rest:

```
int check_input(void)
{   
  char check = 0;
  int return_value = 0;
  int num = 0;
  int correct_input = 0;
  int choice = 0;

  do 
  {
    return_value = scanf("%c",&check);

    if (return_value == EOF)
    {
      return EOF;
    }
    else if (return_value == 1)
    {       
        if(check == 'A')
        {
            choice = 1;
            correct_input = 1;
        }
        else if(check == 'B')
        {
            choice = 2;
            correct_input = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error, Please input correct choice(A/B):");

        }   
    }
  } while (correct_input == 0);

  return choice;
}
```

For now dont know how to ignore spaces. Any help appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `isblank()` or `isspace()` function.  Do note the difference between the two.

Comment: Or you could make `scanf()` do it for you.  If you want to ignore all leading whitespace, including newlines, then simply insert a space character at the beginning of your `scanf()` format.

Comment: Instead of reading a single character, read a whole line with `fgets()`. Then trim surrounding whitespace and check if it's a single character.

Comment: I added space in scanf ,  `scanf( " %c", &check)` Problem is if i type "  AS" it reads as valid input